# Azure DevOps Build Test Fails with dotnet 7 version

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, azure-devops

we are trying to build dot net application with version 6  or 7 below is the error we we getting on build test task. If anyone knows the below error please let me know to resolve.

**Error**
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\7.0.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(197,5): error MSB4044: The "GenerateDepsFile" task was not given a value for the required parameter "AssemblyVersion". [D:\a\1\s\src\common\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx.csproj]

Comment: Please share the complete logs and how the pipeline was setup including the build agent pool used. The information you have provided is very little to know the root cause.